# React doesn't work on browser side?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I used `webpack-dev-server` to provide the bundled `app.js` in memory. Everything is ok. Then I use webpack cli to create a actual `app.js` file in disk and modify the HTML to link it.

But the react doesn't work on browser side then. Every time I click a link on the page, it send a new request to server and get a new page, just like normal web page.

I said "on browser side" because I used server rendering(with react-router). I can get the page, so I think the server rendering works which means the react and react-router works.

I compared the two files. The one provided by webpack-dev-server is 2.8MB and the one in disk is only 922KB.

Here is the config file used by webpack-dev-server:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/client/entry',
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js/',
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/js/',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?experimental'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
}
```

And here is the config file used by webpack cli:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/client/entry',
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/public/js',
        filename: 'app.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: @WiredPrairie nothing

Comment: Are you initializing React, etc? This may have nothing to do with the packing.